# How to test if a value exists in the database without submitting?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'am using JSF2.0/primefaces,

I want to validate a date choosen from a calandar:

```
<p:calendar  value="#{bean.date1}" style="width: 50px" showOn="button" />
```

but I want that the validation will be done without submitting the result , what I want is that when I will choose the date and it dont exists in the database a message will be dispalys to the user.
I have write a function that test if the date exists in the database but I don't know what I should do next!

```
public void validateDate() throws ParseException
 {
  FindIssue fdate=new FindIssue();
  ArrayList<String> listdate=fdate.FindListdateCreation();
  Iterator itdate=listdate.iterator();
  while (itdate.hasNext())
  {
DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date=out.format(itdate.next());

  if(!date.equals(formatingDateTime(date1))) 
  {
      System.out.println("invalide date ");
  }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. use `<f:ajax event` to asynchronously call your date checking logic.